# How to getImage src which is in a td tag in JSoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.stockexchangeofmauritius.com/officialquotes/").get();

Element table = doc.select("table").get(0);

Elements trs = table.select("tr");
Iterator trIter = trs.iterator();
boolean firstRow = true;
trIter.next();
stmtt = conn1.createStatement();


if (count < 1) {
    while (trIter.hasNext()) {
        Element tr = (Element) trIter.next();
        if (firstRow) {
            firstRow = false;
            continue;
        }            
        Elements tds = tr.select("td");
        Iterator tdIter = tds.iterator();
        int tdCount = 1;
        String symbol = null;
        String trend = null;
        String nominal = null;
        while (tdIter.hasNext()) {
                    Element td = (Element) tdIter.next();
                    switch (tdCount++) {

                        case 1:
                            symbol = String.valueOf(td.text());
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            trend = td.getElementsByTag("img").get(0).absUrl("src");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            nominal = String.valueOf(td.text());
                            break;
```

The `img` tag is found in a `td` of the table, thus I'm unable to get the text value. The code has been edited. Does .getElementsByTag returns a string value??? I have never did this for JSoup. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the td tag in question you can use the following to retrieve the image src:
`td.getElementsByTag("img").get(0).attr("src")`

If you want the entire path including the website name use the following instead:
`td.getElementsByTag("img").get(0).absUrl("src")`

Comment: I have edited the code, can you please look at it,, it is still not working